# Have or had, if you were speaking hypothetically?

Tags: grammar, usage

So, here's the sentence:

> They usually ask: if you were stranded on an island, what’s the one thing
>   you’d wish you had?

So is it *have* or *had* in this example, and why? (if it even makes a difference)

Answer (score 1):

A finite clause complementing *wish* is almost always hypothetical (irrealis, 'subjunctive'):

> He wishes (that) he had a million dollars.  *but not*
>   He wishes (that) he *has a million dollars.

The irrealis quality is often expressed with a past-form modal verb

> He wishes that he might/could/would win the race.

The only exception is situations where *wish* in some sense "effects" the desired outcome. In a fairy tale, for instance, where the genie grants the hero a wish, he might say

> I wish that I **may** marry the princess . . .

and the story proceeds inevitably to the nuptial.

Comment: It amazes me how many English speakers get this wrong. Even those who are supposedly in the know. :)

Comment: so the sentence example I used was right?

Comment: @strawberries Your sentence is correct.